# How to find all the solutions for a NQueens problem given that one queen is fixed at some column?

Tags: java, arrays, backtracking

This is all about the famous NQueens problem. My program works fine (backtrack approach). It finds all the solutions for a given board size.
Code is shown below.

**I'm trying to modify the code so that I can find all the solutions for a given column of the first queen.** I don't want to change the position of first queen. For an example it will provide me with the solution of

```
  [2, 0, 3, 1, 4] and [2, 4, 1, 3, 0]
```

when I set the first queen at 2, board size 5 (third column, index starts from zero).

I tried this by setting different values for k (and board[k] as well) but doesn't quite reach the goal.
**Any hints will be appreciated.**

Here is my code. Removed details about `place` method since it shouldn't be changed to achieve my new goal.

```
public class NQueensAllSolutions
{
    //  Board size
    static int size = 8;
    
    //  One dimensional array to store the column number for all queens.
    static int[] board = new int[size];
    
    //  This method will check the validity for a new queen. works fine.
    static boolean place(int k)
    {
        .
        .       
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int k;
        
        long t=0;   //  for counting total found solutions

        k = 0;
        board[k] = -1;      

        while(k >= 0) {

            board[k]++;

            while(board[k] < size && !(place(k))) board[k]++;

            if(board[k] < size) {
                if(k == size-1) {   //  a solution is found.
                    
                    t++;                    
                    
                    //System.out.println("\n\nTotal: "+t+" --> "+Arrays.toString(board));   
                }
                else {
                    k++; board[k] = -1;
                }
            }
            else {              
                k--;    //  backtrack.              
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("\n\nTotal: "+t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Did you try debugging when you played with k and board[k] values?

Comment: The output you showed for a board size 5?

Comment: Yes, board size 5. I will put this in my problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep `k` greater than 0 in the `while` loop:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Queens
{
    static int size = 5;
    static int[] board = new int[size];

    static boolean isValid(int k)
    {
        int c1 = board[k];
        int c2 = board[k];
        for(int r=k-1;r>=0;r--)
        {
            c1--;
            c2++;
            if(board[r] == board[k] || board[r] == c1 || board[r] == c2)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int t = 0;

        // Set the first queen position
        board[0] = 2;

        int k = 1;
        board[k] = -1;

        // k must stay greater than 0
        while(k >= 1) {
            board[k]++;
            while(board[k] < size && !isValid(k))
                board[k]++;
            if(board[k] < size) {
                if(k == size-1) {
                    t++;
                    System.out.println("Solution "+t+" --> "+Arrays.toString(board));
                }
                else {
                    k++;
                    board[k] = -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Solution 1 --> [2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
Solution 2 --> [2, 4, 1, 3, 0]
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a generalized version that can force a queen at position (`fixedRow`, `fixedCol`).
The key change is the new `getNextCol()` method, which is used to get the next possible column for a queen. On row `fixedRow`, the only possible column is `fixedCol`. On the other rows, all columns are possible.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Queens
{
    static int size = 5;
    static int fixedRow = 2;
    static int fixedCol = 0;
    static int[] board = new int[size];

    static boolean isValid(int k)
    {
        int c1 = board[k];
        int c2 = board[k];
        for(int r=k-1;r>=0;r--)
        {
            c1--;
            c2++;
            if(board[r] == board[k] || board[r] == c1 || board[r] == c2)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int getNextCol(int k, int col)
    {
        if(k == fixedRow) {
            // Only one possible move on this row
            return col == -1 ? fixedCol : size;
        }
        else {
            // Try the next column
            return col+1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int t = 0;
        int k = 0;
        board[k] = -1;

        while(k >= 0) {
            board[k] = getNextCol(k, board[k]);
            while(board[k] < size && !isValid(k))
                board[k] = getNextCol(k, board[k]);
            if(board[k] < size) {
                if(k == size-1) {
                    t++;
                    System.out.println("Solution "+t+" --> "+Arrays.toString(board));
                }
                else {
                    k++;
                    board[k] = -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Solution 1 --> [1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
Solution 2 --> [4, 2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I was so close to get there! Thank you, could you do me a little favor? What else I need to do to apply this for other queens? Say I want to fix any queen (only one) to any column. @Olivier.